# How to add a string only to a subset of a character column in R

Tags: r, paste

I have a dataframe similar to this below:

```html
# A tibble: 32 × 3
  sample     IP  value
   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
 1 prot1    -IP      0
 2 prot1   Mock      0
 3 prot2    -IP      0
 4 prot2   Mock      0
 5 prot3    -IP      0
 6 prot3   Mock      0
# … with 22 more rows
```

I want to add a string specified by a variable (`a <- ("str")` ) only in front of the `-IP` containing rows in the `IP` column, obtaining something like:

```html
    # A tibble: 32 × 3
      sample     IP  value
       <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
     1 prot1 str-IP      0
     2 prot1   Mock      0
     3 prot2 str-IP      0
     4 prot2   Mock      0
     5 prot3 str-IP      0
     6 prot3   Mock      0
    # … with 22 more rows
```

I guess we can use a combination of `paste` and `filter` but I want to keep the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a precise solution, we can use `sub` here:

```r
df$IP <- sub("-IP", paste0(a, "-IP"), df$IP, fixed=TRUE)
```

Another option, using `ifelse` with `grepl`:

```r
df$IP <- ifelse(grepl("^-IP$", df$IP, fixed=TRUE), paste0(a, "-IP"), df$IP)
```

Comment: Second solution can be a bit more general with this minor edit: `df$IP <- ifelse(grepl('^-IP$', df$IP, fixed=TRUE), paste0(a, df$IP), df$IP)`. And good old indexing is an alternative: `df$IP[grepl('^-IP$', df$IP), 'IP'] <- paste0(a, df$IP[grepl('^-IP$', df$IP), 'IP'])`. But anyway the `sub` solution seems simplest :).

Comment: The `sub` solution worked only if I simplified the argument from `"^-IP$"` to `"-IP"`. You have any clue why? I am still very new to coding.